# QParallelAnimationGroup getting destroyed before finished

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to figure out why when the code calls the `setAnimation` function multiple times in a short interval, the animation gets destroyed before finishing.

```cpp
void DisplayUi::setAnimation(QList<QWidget*> toShowList)
{
    // Necessary to disable the layout while the animation is running.
    QGridLayout* layout = p_ui->thumbnailGridLayout;
    layout->setEnabled(false);

    QParallelAnimationGroup* animationGroup = new QParallelAnimationGroup();

    QVariantAnimation* frame_ani = nullptr;
    QEasingCurve::Type curve = QEasingCurve::Type::Linear;
    int duration = 400;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < toShowList.size(); i++) {
        QWidget* widget = toShowList[i];
        //qDebug() << "pending show";

        QGraphicsOpacityEffect* op_eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
        QPropertyAnimation* op_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(op_eff, "opacity");
        op_ani->setEasingCurve(curve);
        op_ani->setDuration(duration);

        int startValue = 0;

        QGraphicsOpacityEffect* eff =
            dynamic_cast<QGraphicsOpacityEffect*>(widget->graphicsEffect());

        if (eff) {
            qDebug() << "eff:" << eff->opacity();
            startValue = eff->opacity();
        }

        op_eff->setOpacity(startValue);
        op_ani->setStartValue(startValue);
        op_ani->setEndValue(1);

        widget->setGraphicsEffect(op_eff);
        widget->show();

        animationGroup->addAnimation(op_ani);
    }

    // Rebuild the rows and columns of the layout
    // according to the framePerColumn value.
    QList<QWidget*> widgetList;
    while (layout->count()) {
        widgetList << layout->takeAt(0)->widget();
    }

    int framePerColumn = p_ui->framePerColumn->value();
    for (int i = 0; i < widgetList.size(); i++) {
        layout->addWidget(widgetList[i], i / framePerColumn, i % framePerColumn);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < widgetList.size(); i++) {

        QLayoutItem* dummyItem = p_ui->dummyScrollAreaLayout->itemAt(i);
        QLayoutItem* item = layout->itemAt(i);
        if (!dummyItem || !item) {
            qInfo() << "invalid dummyItem?";
            continue;
        }

        QWidget* widget = item->widget();
        QPoint pos = dummyItem->widget()->pos();

        frame_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(widget, "pos");
        frame_ani->setEasingCurve(curve);
        frame_ani->setDuration(duration);

        if (toShowList.contains(widget))
            frame_ani->setStartValue(pos);
        else
            frame_ani->setStartValue(widget->pos());

        frame_ani->setEndValue(pos);

        animationGroup->addAnimation(frame_ani);
    }

    animationGroup->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    connect(animationGroup, &QAbstractAnimation::destroyed, this, [this] {
        qDebug() << "destroyed";
    });

    connect(animationGroup, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, this, [=] {
        qDebug() << "finished";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < toShowList.size(); i++) {
            toShowList[i]->setGraphicsEffect(nullptr);
        }
        layout->setEnabled(true); // Reenable the layout.
    });
}



void DisplayUi::createFrame()
{
    DeviceUi* d = new DeviceUi();
    //...
    d->ui->frame->hide();
    p_ui->thumbnailGridLayout->addWidget(d->ui->frame);

    QTimer::singleShot(200, this, [=]() {
    // Necessary for the dummyScrollAreaLayout to get updated.
        setAnimation({d->ui->frame});
    });
}
```

What this code does is:

1. Create a new frame, set it hidden, append it to a layout and call the animation.
   The animation sets the frame's opacity to 0, then calls `show()`.
2. Add a new `QPropertyAnimation` and starts the `QParallelAnimationGroup`.

However, when called so often, the `QAbstractAnimation` is executed and it emits the `destroyed` signal before getting started.

Adding the `QParallelAnimationGroup*` to the class header messes up with everything, as it can be called multiple times in a short interval.

Comment: You phrased your description as if the animation was calling `show` (sorry if I misunderstood) but there is not `show` in the slot connected to `finished`. Can you please clarify? Little other thing, I am unsure what the `QTimer` (`// Necessary for the dummyScrollAreaLayout to get updated.`) was for but I believe you could call some method on your layout for it to calculate without being shown (from my memory, it is the `activate()` method).